# php get the upcoming date from month of day

Tags: php, date, datetime

In php if I have the day of month like:

```
$day = 19;
```

How can I get the next occurrence of `$day`,

```
function nextOccurrence($day) {
    /// ???
    return $date;
}
```

if today is `2016-12-18` then `nextOccurence(19)`  should return tomorrow(19) `2016-12-19`.

and if today is `2016-12-19` or a higher date in December then `nextOccurence(19)` should return the `19th` of the next month i.e. `2017-01-19`.

Comment: `date('d')`/`date('j')`/`date('n')` shows you what you need.

Comment: that gives the numerical representation of current month.. not what i need

Comment: can you please describe how can i use that in my case?

Comment: `date('j')` gives you day number. Check it and do what you need.

Comment: isn't there an `strtotime` next 19th option, that I can use instead of doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

If today is <= from the day you want, just add (day - today) days,
else, add one month to the current day and subtract (today - day).

```
<?php

$day = 19;

echo nextOccurrence($day);

function nextOccurrence($day) {
    $currentDay = date('d');
    if ($day > $currentDay) {
        // Get the timestamp of $day in this month
        $date = strtotime('+' . ($day - $currentDay) . ' days');
    } else {
        // Get the timestamp of the current day in next month, and subtract the days difference
        $date = strtotime('+1 month -' . ($currentDay - $day) . ' days');
    }
    return date('Y-m-d', $date);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
echo '<br>Today is :' . date('Y-m-d');
echo '<br>Next day is : ' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate Date, please use DateTime Object.

- Step1: Initialize the date
- Step2: Create an interval of 1 Day.
- Step3: Add this interval to your Date
- Step4: Return date as a string.

It works even if your are the Feb 28th, 2008.

```
<?php
//Step 1
$date = new DateTime('2008-02-29'); //or new DateTime(date('Y-m-d')) for today
//Step2
$oneDay = new DateInterval('P1D')
//Step3
$date->add($oneDay);
//Step4 will return 1 (March 1st)
echo $date->format('d') . "\n";
```

To find the next occurence :

```
$nextOccurence = new DateTime();
while ($day != $nextOccurence->format('d')){
    $nextOccurence->add($oneDay);
}
```

Comment: what does P10D do?

Comment: Sorry, this is P1D, I edited. That means : **P**eriod **1** **D**ay .

Comment: I ran this but it is just adding to the number of days.. I need to get the next occurence of a day..

Comment: I edited to add a loop until the good day. Be careful to test $day. if $day is -1 or 32 you will have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use strtotime and add 1 month(if month is february then get *last day of next month*) and add +1 day.

```
function nextOccurrence($day) {  
    $date_d = date('d');    
    if ($date_d <= $day) {
        if($date_d > 28)  
        {
            $get_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("last day of next month")); 
        }
        else
        {
            $get_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+1 month"));
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        $stop_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($get_date . ' +1 day'));
    }
     echo $stop_date;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/700393)**

Comment: Thanks.. but I don't see where I can put the input `$day` ?

Comment: @ Mubashar Abbas : pass your date in $date_d.

Comment: ok i set the `$date_d` to 20, now the result should have been `2016-12-20 00:00:00` but it gave `2017-01-20 00:00:00`

Comment: for `<= 19` it should be next month, bcz that day has past, but for `> 19` it should give the date with `$day` from this month.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the below code:

```
function nextOccurrence($day) {
    $today = date("d");
    if ($today <= $day) {
        return $retDate = date("d-M-Y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . '+1 month'));
    } else {
        return $retDate = date("d-M-Y", strtotime(date("Y-M-$d") . "+1 day"));
    }

}
```

hope problem solved.

Comment: return $retDate = date("$day-M-Y", strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . '+1 month'));

Comment: replace above line with first return